# In making a mask, how do I remove the outer area and lay the inner area atop video?

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor, masking

This is only my first time in making masks in Blender and I wish to learn this for my future motion graphics. 
See photo below. How do I erase the shaded area surrounding the bezier on a maroon rectangle and later drop the inner area on top of video?

Assistance apprecitated. Thanks in advance. 
[image]

Comment: Connect the mask output to the *Fac* Input of the mix node.

Answer (score 1):

### Compositing

Solution with compositing like you suggested with the screenshot.
Using the mask as an factor input mentioned in the comments above.
(I just use the colors as a placeholder, you can use renders, movies, images...)
[image: composition solution]

### Video Sequence Editor (VSE)

Another solution would be to use the Video Sequence Editor (VSE). You can add both the render or what you want to cut out and the video. The video under the 'overlay'. On the strip you want to overlay you can add a mask modifier. Don't forget to change the blend type of the strip above to 'Alpha Over' or 'Over Drop' otherwise it will replace the image below.
[image: VSE solution]
[image: VSE mask modifier]

### Inverting the mask

To invert the mask, go to the mask editor (image editor and then select the mask view). In the right panel (N-Panel) there is the option for the mask layer. On the right of the 'Opacity' input there is the invert switch (white and black rectangle). By clicking it you can invert the mask.

(Tip: If you don't see a change. In the composition may enable auto render. In the VSE press 'Refresh Sequencer'.

[image]

Comment: I would only add that if you want to reverse the hold out function, then switch the value in the Mask editor window.

Comment: Thx, I have edited the information to the answer.

Comment: Press Refresh Sequencer... take a drink.